# Undefined behavior lead to different results in my C program

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I guess an undefined behavior causes some trouble in my project. To better illustrate my problem, I present a short example below:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"

typedef uint32_t ntype_t;

int main(){
    int foo[2] = {0, 1};
    ntype_t a,b;
    int * pt = &foo[1];

    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    printf("%d\n", pt[a-b]);
}
```

### Problem

I compiled this program without any options, and got a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. While I compiled this program with `-O2`, the result was `0`. The problem is also relevant with platform, and my environment is Ubuntu linux 3.11.0-15-generic + GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: What's the question? Is there UB in the code, or why it causes different results?

Comment: It undefined behaviour, so it can do anything it wants and all results are acceptable.

Comment: @KirilKirov I guess negative index(`a-b`) for a array is an undefined behavior, and I want to know how it causes different results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You own the memory pointed to by `pt`. So you can dereference using `*pt`. This is equivalent to `*(pt + 0)` or `pt[0]`.

It turns out that you can reference both `pt[0]` and `pt[-1]` since pointer arithmetic is well-defined on your underlying `foo` array.

But you don't own the memory at `pt[a - b]` since `a - b` is **not** -1 but rather a very large positive number as `a` and `b` are unsigned types so the result will be an unsigned type too.

Hence you get *undefined behaviour*.

Undefined behaviour is exactly that: you can expect *anything* to happen.

Comment: Thanks for you thoughtful explanation, when I altered `ntype_t;` to `uint8_t`, `a-b` is conversed to -1(int) and the result is 0, so how can I get a determinate result without modifying the data type?

Comment: You'll need to cast *both* `a` *and* `b`. (Casting just one of them is insufficient since `int` is promoted to `unsigned`.)

Answer (score 2):

You are subtracting a larger unsigned integer from a smaller one. This causes an ovetflow. The result is a huge number, likely 2^32-1. This index is beyond your array boundaries.  That's the UB you are looking for.